# La pagina en mi WebView abre una nueva pestaña y no puedo acceder - Android

Tags: android, activity, webview, webview-android

Estoy haciendo una app en la cual una opción solo es un activity que consta solamente de un WebView en donde tengo la pagina de la empresa. El problema ocurre que la pagina  tiene un botón donde abre una nueva pestaña manteniendo la anterior, entonces se queda el WebView en la primer pantalla y nunca puedo ver la segunda pestaña que genera.

Intente usar el shouldOverrideUrlLoading para detectar el cambio pero como no recarga la pagina sino que abre la nueva pestaña no genera el evento.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.pagina);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webView.loadUrl(URL);
    }
```

Desde ya Gracias

Comment: Coloca el codigo que hayas ingreso y resume un poco el problema. Con decir que necesitas abrir otra pestaña, desde tu web en tu webview hubiera sido casi suficiente para saber que necesitas.

Comment: Bienvenido, importante revisar [ask] y editar tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: disculpen, por querer explicar mejor, escribí mucho, ya edite y agregue el simple código que contiene el activity gracias!

Comment: @maxi.f no sera que el boton de la pagina en realidad no funciona?  ya lo probaste en un navegador?

Comment: El boton funciona correcto, si en lugar de abrir por mi webview ejecuto para que lo abra la pagina en chrome la puedo usar perfectamente

Answer (score 0):

Buenas te recomiendo que revises primero los permisos del manifest. Al menos debes incluir este:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Luego en el xml de tu actividad principal añadir el elemento webview que ocupará toda la pantalla.

```
    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Por último, en la actividad principal te dejo los elementos necesarios para mostrar tu página web:

fuera de onCreate:

```
private WebView webview;
```

Dentro de onCreate:

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
webSettings.setUserAgentString("Nombre Agente");
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webview.loadUrl("url de la web");
```

Y para navegar con el botón hacia atrás del dispositivo móvil puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    WebView mWebView;
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                    mWebView.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Saludos!